# REACT NATIVE Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:. New update from iid broke the project

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native

Some info first: this is not my workstation, this notebook is owned by the company i work on, i do have some access.

Some things are weird with the enviroment, but we can work, I`m not the only one having problems with the enviroment, but i dont think this is related to env, but with the latest iid update.

The way i have to start the project is by two terminals where

- the usage of sudo su is to prevent some bugs within our enviroment

  ```
  1 > [sudo su] yarn react-native start
  2 > [sudo su] yarn android:android:debug
  ```

which results in this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :@react-native-firebase_iid
```

**import info :@react-native-firebase_iid received an update as of yesterday july/07/2020
so before that all was working

follows the package.json file

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.6.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^6.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.1.0", DOWNGRADING DID NOT HELP ( version bellow )
    "@react-native-firebase/iid": "^6.3.4", DOWNGRADING DID NOT HELP ( version bellow )
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.60.4",
    "react-native-barcode-builder": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-config": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-dialog": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-flip-card": "^3.5.5",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-keychain": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-map-link": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.25.0",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-touch-id": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "uninstall": "0.0.0"
  },
```

yarn list --pattern "@react-native-firebase" results in

```
yarn list v1.22.4
├─ @react-native-firebase/analytics@6.7.2
├─ @react-native-firebase/app-types@6.7.1
├─ @react-native-firebase/app@6.7.1
└─ @react-native-firebase/iid@6.7.1
Done in 0.49s.
```

Following another questions similar to this problem gave me these options

```
rm -rf node_modules/
rm -rf yarn.lock
./gradlew clean
yarn react-native link react-native-firebase
yarn react-native start --reset-cache
tryng to sync the android project on android studio
IOS also having problems
following the iid instalation to react native from firebase
```

none worked, sadly

yarn react-native link react-native-firebase results in

````
        $ /home/raiadrogasil.com/kamoraes/Workspace/ProjetosRd/univers-app-react/node_modules/.bin/react-native link react-native-firebase
        warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
          - react-native-maps: https://npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps
        Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
        error Unknown dependency. Make sure that the package you are trying to link is already installed in your "node_modules" and present in your "package.json" dependencies. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
        error Command failed with exit code 1.
        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.```
````

**settings.gradle**

```
    rootProject.name = 'universAppReact'
    include ':react-native-touch-id'
    project(':react-native-touch-id').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-touch-id/android')
    include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
    project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
    apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
    include ':@react-native-firebase_app'
    project(':@react-native-firebase_app').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, './../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/android')
    include ':app'
```

build.gradle

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        }
        repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        }
    }
```

the project stopped working after we tried a new clone, of the project ro resolve some issues.
please if there are needed any more info, do tell me.

Comment: Firebase Instance ID (IID) is an internal component of Firebase that generates unique IDs for each app instance. Many Firebase SDKs are moving over from IID to Firebase Installation Services (FIS), which roughly serves the same purpose. You might want to remove the dependency on `iid` and see if it then asks for a different SDK dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with version of package. In my case i cleared the up arrow before the version and it worked. Don't worry after all i revert changes and all good.

```
"@react-native-firebase/iid": "6.3.4", DOWNGRADING DID NOT HELP ( version bellow )
"@react-native-firebase/iid": "^6.3.4", DOWNGRADING DID NOT HELP ( version bellow )
```